# How to duplicate string in bash?

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I have the following string in bash

```
str="kallel"
```

I want to create from `str` an `str2`. The `str2` contains `str` duplicated till the length = 20. So the result should be like this:

```
str2="kallelkallelkallelka"
```

How to do in in bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
str="kallel"
str2="${str}"
while (( ${#str2} < 20 ))
do
  str2="${str2}${str}"
done
str2="${str2:0:20}"
```

Comment: Line #2 (`str2="${str}"`) is redundant.

Comment: @devnull How so? It's assigning the value of one variable (`${str}`) as the initial value of a second variable (`str2`) before the loop... It reduces the loop count by one as well as overwriting any previous value `str2` might have had, avoiding an explicit `str2=""`...

Comment: `str2` is unassigned, so length is zero.  Try `echo ${#foo}`.

Comment: @devnull It's *probably* unassigned, but I don't know that for sure if this is part of a bigger script. Better to be safe.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ str="kallel"

$ str2=$(printf "$str%.0s" {1..20})
$ echo "$str2"
kallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallelkallel

$ str2=$(printf "$str%.0s" {1..3})
$ echo "$str2"
kallelkallelkallel

$ n=5
$ str2=$(printf "$str%.0s" $(seq "$n"))
$ echo "$str2"
kallelkallelkallelkallelkallel
```

Comment: Gotta say I love this use of printf.  It took some noodling, but now I see that printf will repeat it's format string for every argument passed to it (if there are more arguments than replaceable % parameters).  The %.0s eats up an argument but adds it to the output as 0 length.  Even though it's a little obscure, I think it's a better solution than yes | head | xargs | sed | cut that I presented.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for a while loop personally then cut it at the end.

While the length of `str2` is less than 20, add `str` to `str2`. 
Then, for good measure, we cut at the end to max 20 characters.

```
#!/bin/bash
str="kallel"
str2=""
while [ ${#str2} -le 20 ]
do
    str2=$str2$str
done
str2=`echo $str2 | cut -c1-20`
```

Comment: error in this line `while [ ${#stringZ} -le 20]`  `line 35: [: missing `]'`

Comment: There should be a space after `20` and before `]`. Fixed.

Comment: blocked. looks like infinite loop.

Comment: Counting the length of `$stringZ` will always return the same number, since the loop only modifies `$str2` and not `$stringZ`...

Comment: sorry guys - just put it together without checking. should work now

Answer (score 2):

I am 100% stealing this answer from [Bash : Duplicate a string variable n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835374/bash-duplicate-a-string-variable-n-times) but I thought it bore repeating (despite being on a 6 year old question):

```
$ yes "kallel" | head -20  | xargs | sed 's/ //g' | cut -c1-20
kallelkallelkallelka
```