# How to duplicate strings in each line using bash?

Tags: string, bash

I have a text file containing strings in each line like this:

```
'abc',
'dog',
'zebra',
```

I want to make it like:

```
'abc', 'abc',
'dog', 'dog',
'zebra', 'zebra',
```

How best to do it in bash?

Comment: This could work too...`paste -d " " dupcol.csv dupcol.csv`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to duplicate string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16484887/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)/\1 \1/' dupcol.csv
```

The `.*` says to match any character on a line, repeatedly. The `( )` around it says to store the match in the first register (`\1`). Then the full match is output twice.

I just usually default to using sed’s `-r` option to make for cleaner (extended) regexes. However, omitting the `-r` enables `&` to match the full pattern. So a simpler version of this special case where you want to keep the full match is:

```
sed -r 's/.*/& &/' dupcol.csv
```

If you want to change the file in-place, add the `-i` option.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Would be more informative  if you also explain what `\1 \1` does.

Comment: As you are using everything matched you can just use `&` without any capture groups or need for `-r`. `sed 's/.*/& &/'`

Comment: Awesome tip on &. I had originally tried that but now see that it does not work with -r. I've added this into the answer. Thanks!