# Bash : Duplicate a string variable n times

Tags: string, bash, variables, duplicates

I have a variable : `str='abc'`

I would like to copy it n times, with a space between each string, so the `echo` gives, for n=3 :

```
echo $str
abc abc abc
```

I don't want a space after the last `abc`

I've  already seen the link mentionned but they doesn't help. The last answer from @Amadan is the good one thanks, but I can't accept it :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to duplicate string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16484887/608639), [Linux command to repeat a string n times](https://superuser.com/q/86340/173513), [How to duplicate strings in each line using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32001182/608639), [How can I repeat a character in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5349718/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww. I thought I looked through all of those, but the space separator makes this a non-duplicate

Comment: Here's something relevant though: https://superuser.com/a/462400/297512

Comment: `str=$(yes "$str" | head -3 | xargs echo)`

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
eval echo {1..$n} | sed "s/[[:digit:]]*/${var}/g"
```

**Example:**

```
n=3
var=abc

eval echo {1..$n} | sed "s/[[:digit:]]*/${var}/g"
abc abc abc
```

Comment: Note: has problems when `$var` has regexp special characters (or slash); fine otherwise.

Comment: @Amadan, is it OK by replacing '/' with '|' symbol in sed delimiters like `eval echo {1..$n} | sed "s|[[:digit:]]*|${var}|g"` ?

Comment: Of course. But then your variable is restricted from having `|` in it.