# Bash - Use a variable as top limit in range

Tags: bash, shell, tee, brace-expansion

I am trying to write a script that takes a parameter from the cli and uses that number as a top limit in a range for creating a number of files.

```
num_files=$1
time parallel -N 10 'cat source.txt | tee copy{1}.txt copy{2}.txt copy{3}.txt copy{4}.txt copy{5}.txt copy{6}.txt copy{7}.txt copy{8}.txt copy{9}.txt copy{10}.txt' ::: {1..$numfiles}
```

I've tried every type of quoting I can think of but, oddly, the only output I get is a single file named `copy{1..200}.txt` (if I pass in 200).  So the number I pass in is getting picked up correctly, its just not working as I'd expect.

Is this possible?

Comment: `{1..$numfiles}` does now work as expected, brace expansion happens before variable does... see this [link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D) at least in `bash`

Comment: You could use `seq` to generate your numbers. See _man seq_.

Comment: See the last script in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56836378/1745001 for how to use `seq` to generate multiple strings that you could use as file names.

Comment: Great, `seq` worked as I'd hoped.  Thanks a lot!